# SQL subtract using multiple CASE WHEN ELSE resulting in GROUP BY issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have the below query working in SSMS. (FYI I am hiding column names and db name as sensitive information)

```
SELECT  ONE.PROJECT_CODE as 'A',
        sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE) as 'B',
        TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0) as 'C',
        TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0) - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE) as 'D',
        (((TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0)) - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE))/2) as 'E'
FROM X.dbo.AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW as ONE
LEFT JOIN X.dbo.CFMS_Charters_FlightsAndGrossMargin_IncICFLIGHT as TWO
    ON ONE.PROJECT_CODE = TWO.Charter_Number
LEFT JOIN X.dbo.TB_ACS_CARPAS_OUTSTANDING as THREE
    ON ONE.PROJECT_CODE = THREE.Project and TWO.Charter_Number = THREE.Project
WHERE ONE.CT_DEADLINE between '1/2/2021' and '2/28/2021'
and ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE= 'ACS 50% GM'
and ONE.CT_TRANTYPE= 'MSC'
GROUP BY ONE.PROJECT_CODE, TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin, THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING
Having sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE) <> 0
```

However, what I want to do is to have the below three lines in the `SELECT` dependent if `THREE.CENTRE = 'ACS 50% GM'`.

```
TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0) as 'C',
TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0) - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE) as 'D',
TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0)) - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE))/2) as 'E'
```

If `ACS 50% GM` doesn't exist, then I want to remove the `ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTNADING, 0)`.

I believe I need to do `CASE WHEN` for each line? I have tried the below but I am getting `column X.dbo.TB_ACS_CARPAS_OUTSTANDING.Centre' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` and I'm not 100% why?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT  ONE.PROJECT_CODE as 'A',
        sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE) as 'B',
CASE WHEN THREE.CENTRE= 'ACS 50% GM'
        THEN TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0)
        ELSE TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin
    END AS 'C',
CASE WHEN THREE.CENTRE = 'ACS 50% GM'
        THEN TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0) - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE)
        ELSE TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE)
    END AS 'D',
CASE WHEN THREE.CENTRE = 'ACS 50% GM'
        THEN (((TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0)) - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE))/2)
        ELSE (TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE))/2
    END AS 'E'
FROM X.dbo.AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW as ONE
LEFT JOIN X.dbo.CFMS_Charters_FlightsAndGrossMargin_IncICFLIGHT as TWO
    ON ONE.PROJECT_CODE = TWO.Charter_Number
LEFT JOIN X.dbo.TB_ACS_CARPAS_OUTSTANDING as THREE
    ON ONE.PROJECT_CODE = THREE.Project and TWO.Charter_Number = THREE.Project
WHERE ONE.CT_DEADLINE between '1/2/2021' and '2/28/2021'
and ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE= 'ACS 50% GM'
and ONE.CT_TRANTYPE= 'MSC'
and THREE.CENTRE= 'ACS 50% GM'
GROUP BY ONE.PROJECT_CODE, TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin, THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING
Having sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE) <> 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting

> column X.dbo.TB_ACS_CARPAS_OUTSTANDING.Centre' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

because you don't add the column `THREE.CENTRE` in `Group BY` Clause. If you need to include this in `SELECT` then you should add it in `Group BY` Clause. Instead of `CASE` you can even use  `IIF()`. if you have no issues in adding `THREE.CENTRE` in `GROUP BY` please try the below code.

```
SELECT  ONE.PROJECT_CODE AS 'A',
        SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE) AS 'B',
        IIF(THREE.CENTRE= 'ACS 50% GM',TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0),TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin) AS 'C',
        IIF(THREE.CENTRE= 'ACS 50% GM',TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0) - SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE),TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE)) AS 'D',
        IIF(THREE.CENTRE= 'ACS 50% GM',(((TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - ISNULL(THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING, 0)) - SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE))/2),((TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin - sum(ONE.HOME_VALUE))/2)) AS 'E'
FROM X.dbo.AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW as ONE
LEFT JOIN X.dbo.CFMS_Charters_FlightsAndGrossMargin_IncICFLIGHT as TWO
    ON ONE.PROJECT_CODE = TWO.Charter_Number
LEFT JOIN X.dbo.TB_ACS_CARPAS_OUTSTANDING as THREE
    ON ONE.PROJECT_CODE = THREE.Project and TWO.Charter_Number = THREE.Project
WHERE ONE.CT_DEADLINE between '1/2/2021' and '2/28/2021'
and ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE= 'ACS 50% GM'
and ONE.CT_TRANTYPE= 'MSC'
GROUP BY ONE.PROJECT_CODE, TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin, THREE.OP_OUTSTANDING,THREE.CENTRE
HAVING SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE) <> 0
```

Comment: Ah a simple IIF - I didn't think about that! This is perfect thank you @Annamalai - it's fine with `THREE.CENTRE` in the `GROUP BY` as well